Can get emojis to show in PHP with MySQL 5.x, but not 8.x
I have a PHP 7.3 project that's currently using MySQL 5.5, with utf8 tables. Some of the tables contain emoji data, which show up fine in the current project. I'm trying to update the project to MySQL 8.x, but when I do, emoji data shows up incorrectly.
First, I updated all the 5.5 tables to use uf8mb4. In this state, the data showed up. I then updated to 5.7, and things continued to work. I dumped this data, updated to 8.0, and reloaded it (I did use the --default-character-set=utf8mb4 flag on both dump and load), and then the data stopped showing up correctly, for example a lightbulb showing up as ðŸ’¡.
I am running each of these services in docker. I was able to update from 5.5 to 5.7 using the same data volume without issue, but when trying to upgrade from 5.7 to 8.0, I got errors I was unable to resolve, and ended up doing a data dump/restore.
An example table with a field with an emoji:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `forums`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `forums` (
  `forumID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `forumType` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'f',
  `parentID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `heritage` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `order` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `gameID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `threadCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`forumID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `heritage` (`heritage`),
  KEY `parentID` (`parentID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11551 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `forums`
--

LOCK TABLES `forums` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `forums` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `forums` VALUES (8003,'ðŸ’¡ Gamers\' Plane development',NULL,'f',2,'0002-8003',3180,3181,4);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `forums` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

To update the table to utf8mb4 I did
ALTER TABLE forums CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

How I'm testing the return of that data:
<?php
$mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql;dbname=gamersplane", 'gamersplane', 'mypass');
$mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$forum = $mysql->query('select * from forums where forumID = 8003')->fetch();
?>
<html>
<header>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</header>
<body>
<?php print_r($forum['title']); ?>
</body>
</html>

I've read [UTF-8 all the way through][1] and
[1]: UTF-8 all the way through and

am using utf8mb4 in the database
have charset=utf8mb4 in my PDO string
have default_charset explicitly set in my php.ini as well as tried setting it at runtime
have tried Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 as a PHP header, as well as a HTML metatag


I'm doubting your claim about the encodig. This usually happens when you change encoding/collation and not when you change versions. The collation of your dump could be wrong as well. But the chance is very small this has anything to do with versions.

wild guess when dumping/restoring data, use --default-character-set=utf8mb4? Check in the DB how its saved already

Wimanicesir You doubt my claim? What am I getting by lying here? Maybe there's missing information, I don't doubt, but I provided the steps I ran so someone could possibly tell me what I'm doing wrong or ask for the information I didn't know to give.

Abdulla Nilam Thanks, and yes, I did use the default-character-set flag. I'll update the question to reflect that info.

Add your code here. It will engage more users to the question

Abdulla Nilam I assume you meant inline to the question instead of gists? If so, done.

you doubt my claim...nobody thinks you're lying on purpose, but many of the questions here occur because people make assumptions that they don't check, or make a mistake when analysing their code or data - we all do that from time to time if we're honest. So we just like to see some evidence of these things if we can, especially when someone makes an assertion which sounds surprising or unlikely. Then  we can more easily rule things in or out as possible causes of the issue :-)

P.S. Your complete guide to issues like this is usually UTF-8 all the way through. I'm not 100% sure this post is a direct duplicate of that, but I'd be surprised if there was nothing relevant in it.

ADyson I totally get that people make mistakes, but that's also why I provided code from the get to. As you said, we do all make mistakes, but if you're mired in it, often you can't see it. An initial statement like I'm doubting your claim is insulting and does nothing to help figure out if it's me being an idiot, or if there's more info needed. And I did read the UTF-8 post, it was referred in a previous question I worded poorly. I did everything there, thus I provided the code here.

ADyson I updated the question with all the steps form the UTF-8 guide that I've taken.

Encoding in DataBases is always a lot of fun! Unfortunately when you change the character set it doesn't update the data, only how the database interprets the data, as well MySQL doesn't perform encoding change on the fly, and always writes down bytes as they are coming from the client. From the example you can see, that ðŸ’¡ is the latin1 representation of the , and when you dump the data it dumps it already in incorrect encoding.
To verify the issue you can try to convert the data with the query:
SELECT
  CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(title USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4)
FROM forums 
WHERE id = 8003;

in your latest MySQL8 environment, it should display emojis correctly. If so, you should try to dump data again, and this time use the charset it was encoded originally, most likely latin1 using --default-character-set=latin1. The dump file should contain emojis instead of ðŸ’¡-like text.
Be aware, that if you have new content in the table, it will be double encoded, or the dump fill will fail, if new text is not compatible with the latin1 encoding, it would be better to do it with the original set, if you still have access to it.

Awesome! I can write a script that'll convert the original data. I think one point of confusion right now is that the database was always uft8, so why is the data latin1? What don't I understand here?

Looks like this worked. I changed it to a update and emojis appeared on the test site. It's strange, because the the site has been UTF8 since it was created, and I did originally try a dump in latin1 with a restore using utf8mb4, and that didn't work.

When data is written to MySQL it's written with the connection's encoding, which is often not specified, and uses the default server setting. For MySQL 5.7 and earlier the default one is latin1, since 8.0 is utf8mb4. To ensure expected encoding, you might want to specify it on the connection level, e.g. mysql:host=mysql;dbname=gamersplane;charset=utf8mb4.
